# Move Pycharm project to another directory

Tags: python, directory, pycharm, project, move

My home dir ran out of space and I wanted to move the PyCharm project to another directory. I ended up copying it because refactoring didn't work.  I deleted the pycache and the zip exception, that had appeared was gone and now everything works as expected. I still use the venv location of my initial project location though, from what I can see in settings/python-interpreter.

Is there anything wrong with this procedure, anything I'm not aware of?
Should I edit some of the files in the .idea folder?

The `$PROJECT_DIR$` variable caught my attention, but I couldn't find where this variable is actually set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A clean way to move your project is right-clicking on your project folder in *"Project view"* (<kbd>Alt +1</kbd> ) , choosing `Refactor` and then `Move Directory`.

- The `$PROJECT_DIR$` variable is dynamic and [taken from the directory your project is in](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/absolute-path-variables.html), so that isn't a problem
- Your `.idea` folder should be recreated by PyCharm even if you completely delete it. However I wouldn't advise deleting your folder mainly because you will loose your  [project-level dictionary](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/spellchecking.html#accept-word) (wordlist).
- [Invalidating caches](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/cleaning-system-cache.html) has a wider impact because it will clear IDE wide settings not just project specific settings. (It's mostly useful if your cache becomes outdated, which tends to manifest itself by inexplicable errors.)

If something goes wrong just open the moved directory as a new project going to `File` `>` `Open`.  For a simple project there are 2 main settings that you should check and may have to adjust:

- In settings *"Settings"* (<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + S</kbd>) go to `Project: your_project_name` and there check that `Project Structure` makes sense and retains your configurations.
- In `Run` `>` [`Edit Configurations`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) make sure that `Script path` and `Working directory` are set to the locations you want.

> Is there anything wrong with this procedure, anything I'm not aware of?

From your description you took the right steps since refactor didn't work, just ensure the above configurations are met and if the IDE doesn't issue any errors you should be good.

> Should I edit some of the files in the .idea folder?

This would rarely be necessary and is generally discouraged. The files in the `.idea` are IDE generated and should not be touched. Any necessary changes should be made using the IDE graphical interface to set configurations (which means you don't have to worry about the contents of `.idea`).

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer (and editing my post, sorry I'm new here!), I had done the above steps you mentioned implicitly while looking through the settings to check  configurations. I checked again, and paths are set correctly as far as I can see.

I'm note sure if deleting the pycache and the zip-exception I received were somehow related, but it did seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: @ChrisW no problem, glad I could be of help. The steps you took were all right, it takes some time getting used to the IDE I went through these exact same doubts some time back.