# PyCharm not recognising folder even though it's in the correct location

Tags: python, directory, path, pycharm

I have renamed a PyCharm project and its directory, but after the renaming, another folder appeared, but PyCharm recognizes it as if it was not in the correct file path (see image below):

[image]

The "VSO-Token-Dashboard" is the new name I gave it (the old one is "VSO-Token-Unlocks"). The old folder remained, however.

Notice the file path under the three macOS circles. It's just a single folder. Unlike the old folder (see below):

[image]

All code and relevant files are in the Dashboard folder and the folder is in fact in the PyCharm folder, but it does not recognize it at the top. See below:

[image]

The main problem with this is: when I delete the Unlocks folder, even though it has nothing in it, the PyCharm project becomes faded out and I can't open it.

No "VSO-Token-Dashboard" project appears in my initial PyCharm page (presumably because, like in the first picture above, it does not recognise the path).

Should I add the Dashboard folder to the correct path? If so, how do I do that, since it's already in the correct folder (PycharmProjects)?

Comment: you shouldn't rename folders - PyCharm may keep all iformation in some file and it still use old values from config file. It would be better to copy to new folder and later in PyChrome use function to create new project from existing code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move Pycharm project to another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65732784/move-pycharm-project-to-another-directory)

Comment: In this case it's hard to figure out just from the symptoms exactly what's going on in the IDE configuration files located in the `.idea` folder. (Usually the more complexity your project has the more dependencies will be in the configuration files -and the exact dependencies are project specific, so solving this for one project might not solve it for the next-, it's generally cleaner to close and open a new project for this kind of change.)